# Not able to compile C source files using make. CMake error Cannot find source files but they are there

Tags: c, cmake, compiler-errors

Im trying to compile the posest C++ library 
[posest : A C/C++ Library for Robust 6DoF Pose Estimation from 3D-2D Correspondences](http://users.ics.forth.gr/%7Elourakis/posest/index.html)
 with make. But when run the `make` I got the following error

```
make
-- LEVMAR_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/local/levmar-2.6
-- LEVMAR_BINARY_DIR = /usr/local/levmar-2.6/w32
-- LAPACKBLAS_DIR = /usr/lib
-- demos will be linked against posest;levmar;lapack;blas;f2c
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  Cannot find source file:

    mlsl/mlsl.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:65 (ADD_DEPENDENCIES):
  Policy CMP0046 is not set: Error on non-existent dependency in
  add_dependencies.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0046" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The dependency target "levmar" of target "binocposest_demo" does not exist.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:64 (ADD_DEPENDENCIES):
  Policy CMP0046 is not set: Error on non-existent dependency in
  add_dependencies.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0046" for policy details.
  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The dependency target "levmar" of target "posest_demo" does not exist.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "posest".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: posest
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/admini/posest-1.2
Makefile:714: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

But the source file `mlsl.c` is already there

Here is the contents of the `CMakeList.txt` file

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(POSEST)

# levmar library
SET(LEVMAR_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/local/levmar-2.6" CACHE PATH "Path to LEVMAR library header")
#ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(${LEVMAR_INCLUDE_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LEVMAR_INCLUDE_DIR})
MESSAGE(STATUS "LEVMAR_INCLUDE_DIR = ${LEVMAR_INCLUDE_DIR}")

IF(MSVC)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(/arch:SSE2)
  # get rid of CRT warnings
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
ENDIF(MSVC)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(mlsl)

ADD_LIBRARY(posest buckets.c lqs.c ransac.c rngs.c prosac.c deal.c p3p.c p4pf.c planep4p.c svd3.c polysolve.c
  poseproj.c posest.c align.c lhm.c sam.c compiler.h lqs.h ransac.h prosac.h p3p.h p4pf.h planep4p.h svd3.h
  polysolve.h poseproj.h posest.h util.h rngs.h sam.h
  mlsl/mlsl.c mlsl/mt19937ar.c mlsl/redblack.c mlsl/sobolseq.c
)

OPTION(BUILD_DEMOS "Build demo programs?" TRUE)

# demo program
IF(BUILD_DEMOS)
  # paths to levmar & lapack/blas libraries
  SET(LEVMAR_BINARY_DIR "${LEVMAR_INCLUDE_DIR}/w32" CACHE PATH "Path to levmar library")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "LEVMAR_BINARY_DIR = ${LEVMAR_BINARY_DIR}")

  SET(LAPACKBLAS_DIR "/usr/lib" CACHE PATH "Path to lapack/blas libraries")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "LAPACKBLAS_DIR = ${LAPACKBLAS_DIR}")


  # actual names for the lapack/blas/f2c libraries
  SET(LAPACKBLAS_LIB_NAMES "lapack;blas" CACHE STRING "The name of the lapack & blas libraries")
  SET(F2C_LIB_NAME f2c CACHE STRING "The name of the f2c or F77/I77 library")
  # f2c is sometimes equivalent to libF77 & libI77
  #SET(F2C_LIB_NAME "libF77;libI77" CACHE STRING "The name of the f2c or F77/I77 library")

  SET(LIBS posest levmar)
  SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${LAPACKBLAS_LIB_NAMES} ${F2C_LIB_NAME})

  LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}) # location of the posest library
  LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LEVMAR_BINARY_DIR}) # location of the levmar library
  LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LAPACKBLAS_DIR})

  ADD_EXECUTABLE(posest_demo posest_demo.c)
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(posest_demo ${LIBS})

  ADD_EXECUTABLE(binocposest_demo binocposest_demo.c)
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(binocposest_demo ${LIBS})

  MESSAGE(STATUS "demos will be linked against ${LIBS}")

# make sure that the libraries are built before the demos
  ADD_DEPENDENCIES(posest_demo posest levmar)
  ADD_DEPENDENCIES(binocposest_demo posest levmar)
ENDIF(BUILD_DEMOS)
```

Here the Project Directory screenshot.
[image: Project directory]

And the content of the mlsl directory

```
/home/posest-1.2/mlsl/mlsl.c
/home/posest-1.2/mlsl/mlsl.h
/home/posest-1.2/mlsl/mt19937ar.c
/home/posest-1.2/mlsl/mt19937ar.h
/home/posest-1.2/mlsl/redblack.c
/home/posest-1.2/mlsl/redblack.h
/home/posest-1.2/mlsl/sobol.h
/home/posest-1.2/mlsl/soboldata.h
/home/posest-1.2/mlsl/sobolseq.c
```

Im not sure what is the problem. Any help?

Comment: What does your project hierarchy look like? (Is the `mlsl` directory a sibling to the shown CMakeLists.txt file?)

Comment: You said mlsls.c is there but cmake is looking for mlsl.c not mlsls.c

Comment: It was typo. Edit the question. mlsl.c is there and cmake is looking for mlsl.c too

Comment: I edit screenshot of my project directory.

Comment: You don't show the contents of the mlsl directory.

Comment: OK. Edit in the question the content of the mlsl directory. Ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to download the tar file from the website.  It is malformed and won't work.

```
~/swdev/posest-1.2$ ls -ld mlsl/
drw-r--r-- 2 XXX XXXX 4096 Oct  6  2014 mlsl/
~/swdev/posest-1.2$ chmod u+x mlsl/
~/swdev/posest-1.2$ cmake .
```

The sources and directories are required to be readable.  In this case `mlsl` has incorrect permissions and CMake cannot read the file. Use the `chmod` command to fix the permissions on the directory.

Comment: After fixing that I got into another error. `/home/admini/posest-1.2/mlsl/mlsl.c:487:18: error: too many arguments to function ‘dlevmar_bc_der’
             lret=dlevmar_bc_der(func, jacf, lm + 1, (double *)x, m, n, (double *)lb, (double *)ub, (double *)scl, itmax, opts, info, work, NULL, adata);` The line where the error is `lret=dlevmar_bc_der(func, jacf, lm + 1, (double *)x, m, n, (double *)lb, (double *)ub, (double *)scl, itmax, opts, info, work, NULL, adata)`

Comment: @Macedon971 I think that if you can't fix the compiler problem yourself then you should follow the directions on the website on how to contact the author of the software.  Also this is a separate question and should have been posted as a new question.

Comment: ok. will post as a new question and contact the author . The website doesn't give Infos regarding this problem